# How to convert Date to String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to call a function one argument is current time and Date and other is a file name, They both are strings. How can I convert `Date()` to a string. I tried:

```
writeToFile(content: Date(), fileName: "jm.txt")
```

but it gave me error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Date' to expected argument type 'String'

Answer (score 50):

Something like this:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let now = df.string(from: Date())
writeToFile(content: now, fileName: "jm.txt")
```

Comment: let now = df.string(from: selectedDate)

Answer (score 16):

You need to use [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter), as stated in the docs:

> Instances of `DateFormatter` **create `string` representations of `NSDate` objects**, and convert textual representations of dates and times into `NSDate` objects.

In your case, that would look something like this:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

writeToFile(content: formatter.string(from: Date()), fileName: "jm.txt")
```